# iOS 64bit requirement: what's the definition of "new apps" in this case?

Tags: ios, 64-bit, app-store-connect

Apple has a deadline on 1st Feb for new iOS apps to be 64bit. As far as I can find, the entire requirement text is as follows:

> Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6 or later. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a

What does this mean? Is there a precedent for what "uploaded" means? Does it cover apps created in itunes connect but not yet submitted? Or apps uploaded to the new testflight beta service? Or apps in submission but not yet approved? Or apps approved but not yet released? Are there any more in-depth docs on this?

Comment: For any new apps or updates to existing app.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Hi. The answer is simple, though not documented, as far as I know. Anything 32 bit-only that the reviewer receives starting Feb.1 will be automatically rejected. If you sent your submission before that date and the reviewer gets it Feb.1 or later, it will be rejected. This is based in my experience with new requirements and app submissions.

Comment: Did you get an answer on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think "new" indicates the first version of an App to the AppStore.
While "update" indicates any subsequent versions.

I just posted an update which was only 32bit and did not get the arm64 warning.

but did see the warning on a new app about a month ago.

The deadline for updates is june 1st

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172014b